# How to move point to an invisible line (to access an org property when heading is folded)?

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, point

I wrote some code to reschedule all headings under a subtree, but it was failing to get the scheduled date of heading in invisible lines, even though it could access other properties such as the name of the heading.

I debugged it with `edebug` and noticed that the value of `(point)` was always the same, even though different heading names were appearing in the `*Messages*` buffer.

I used a quick fix of showing the full buffer with `(org-shifttab 3)` and wrapping the last function inside a `(org-save-outline-visibility t ...)`, but this seems inelegant and over the top.

I wonder if `search-forward` that I am using in `org-get-scheduled-timestring-at-point` does not move point to invisible lines, even though it forces lines with a match to become visible when used interactively.

Here is a minimal example with an Org-buffer:

```
* heading

** TODO task 1
SCHEDULED: [2019-12-26 Thu]

*** DONE task 0
SCHEDULED: [2019-12-09 Mon]

*** TODO sub task
SCHEDULED: [2019-12-01 Thu]

** TODO task 2
SCHEDULED: [2020-01-01 Wed]
```

and the code:

```lisp
(defun my-org-get-end-of-subtree ()
  "Gets the index at the end of the subtree."
  (save-excursion
    (ignore-errors
      (outline-end-of-subtree)
      (point))))

(defun my-org-get-property ()
  "Returns whether the scheduled date of the heading at point is in the past."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading)
    (message "Point is at %d" (point))
    (search-forward (concat org-scheduled-string " ")) ; move point to the scheduled entry
    (buffer-substring (point) (line-end-position))))

(defun my-org-test-fails ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((end (my-org-get-end-of-subtree)))
    (when end
      (save-excursion
    (org-back-to-heading)
    (while (and (outline-next-heading)
            (< (point) end))
      (message (my-org-get-property)))))))

(defun my-org-test-works ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((end (my-org-get-end-of-subtree)))
    (when end
      (org-save-outline-visibility t
    (save-excursion
      (org-shifttab 3)
      (org-back-to-heading)
      (while (and (outline-next-heading)
              (< (point) end))
        (message (my-org-get-property))))))))
```

The result in the `*Messages*` buffer of running `org-test-fails` and then `org-test-works` is:

```
task 1
Point is at 68
[2019-12-26 Thu]
done task
Point is at 68
[2019-12-26 Thu]
sub task
Point is at 68
[2019-12-26 Thu]
task 2
Point is at 68
[2019-12-26 Thu]
...
task 1
Point is at 79
[2019-12-26 Thu]
done task
Point is at 123
[2019-12-09 Mon]
sub task
Point is at 171
[2019-12-01 Thu]
task 2
Point is at 218
[2020-01-01 Wed]
```

How can I move point to a line that matches text and is invisible? Or how can I get the text of the `SCHEDULED` property of an invisible heading just like I am able to get its heading text?

Comment: Some suggestions:  (1) provide some sample text that forum participants can cut and paste into an org-mode buffer to work with; (2) reduce the issue to just the problem with returning search results on invisible text; i.e., if rescheduling is not needed to resolve this issue, then eliminate rescheduling.  If the goal is just to return a result such as a category of hidden property drawers, then a minimal working example with sample text seems like the most probable way to entice answers from forum participants ....  That being said, some forum participants enjoy a challenge ... :)

Comment: Good points, thanks. I updated the question.

Comment: Is `org-is-scheduled-date-today-or-in-past` your function or does org provide it? You should name your functions with  a different prefix, so that we know what you are (supposed to be) providing and what Org mode is supposed to provide.

Comment: @NickD That was my function, which I had left in by mistake and have now removed. I fixed the prefixes in the question. I also started prefixing my functions for clarity. Thanks for the coding style suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [Using the Property API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Property-API.html#Using-the-Property-API) section of the manual. In particular, doing `(org-entry-get (point) "SCHEDULED")` with `point` at the beginning of the headline returns the scheduled date of the entry, whether the headline is folded or not -- or even hidden: try hiding everything and execute

```
  (org-entry-get 12 "SCHEDULED")
```

on the tree you show above when everything is folded. I get the scheduled date of the headline "task 1": `[2019-12-26 Thu]`.